# Using classes and constructors and create a object name with an array size of 3

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, constructor

I am trying to create an object in the main with an array of three. When i run it, it displays the desired output, but it gives an error and any code after that doesn't run. "Unhandled exception at 0x775FC41F in Grocery.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0036E590."

```
    class GroceryItem {
    public:
    GroceryItem();//default constructor
    GroceryItem(string, double, int, int); // four argument constructor
    void set_item_name(string); // Assigns a value to the data memeber item_name
    void set_item_price(double); //Assigns a value to the data member item_price
    void set_qty_on_hand(int);// Assigns a value to the data member quantity_on_hand.
    void set_qty_purchased(int); // Sets qty_purchased to zero before a customer begins shopping.
    string get_item_name(); // Returns the value of the data memebr item_name.
    double get_item_price(); // Returns the value of the data member item_price
    int get_qty_on_hand(); // Returns the value of the data member quantity_on_hand.
    int get_qty_purchased(); // Retruns the value of the data memebr qty_purchased.
    private:
            string item_name;
            double item_price;
            int quantity_on_hand;
            int quantity_purchased;
     };

   GroceryItem::GroceryItem(string name, double price, int hand, int purchased){
   set_item_name(name);
   set_item_price(price);
   set_qty_on_hand(hand);
   set_qty_purchased(purchased);
   }
   void GroceryItem::set_item_name(string name){
   item_name = name;
   }
   string GroceryItem::get_item_name(){
   return item_name;
   }
   void GroceryItem::set_item_price(double price){
   item_price = price;
   }
   double GroceryItem::get_item_price(){
   return item_price;
   }
  void GroceryItem::set_qty_on_hand(int hand){
  quantity_on_hand = hand;
  }
  int GroceryItem::get_qty_on_hand(){
  return quantity_on_hand;
  }
  void GroceryItem::set_qty_purchased(int purchased){
    if (purchased > 0)
    quantity_purchased = purchased;
   if (purchased <= 0)
   {
    quantity_purchased = 0;
    cout <<"\n cart cannot be negative, it will be set to 0. \n";
    }
   }
   int GroceryItem::get_qty_purchased(){
    return quantity_purchased;
   }



int main(){
int input;
cout <<"Welcome to KMART\n" << "\nHappy Shopping" << endl;
GroceryItem Kmart("Hello", 1234, 1234, 1);
GroceryItem Kmart2("My", 1234, 1234, 1);
GroceryItem Kmart3[SIZE] = {
    { "John", 1234, 1234, 0 },
    { "Mary", 1234, 1234, 0 },
    { "Kevin", 1234, 1234, 0 }

};
//Kmart("jjj", 12, 123, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
cout << Kmart3[i].get_item_name() << "\t" << Kmart3[i].get_item_price() << "\t" <<                   Kmart3[i].get_qty_on_hand() << "\t" << Kmart3[i].get_qty_purchased() << endl;
}
cout << "This is fromt eh four argument constructor" << endl;
cout<<Kmart.get_item_name()<<"\t"<<Kmart.get_item_price()<<"\t"<<Kmart.get_qty_on_hand()<<"\t"<<Kmart.get_qty_purchased()<<endl;
cout << Kmart2.get_item_name() << "\t" << Kmart2.get_item_price() << "\t" << Kmart2.get_qty_on_hand() << "\t" << Kmart2.get_qty_purchased() << endl;
```

}

Comment: The error comes from the Kmart3 output.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared with us the value for SIZE; however, I'm guessing that you probably have it less than 10.  If that were the case, then it would crash later when you're looping through Kmart3.

Making this change should stop the crashing (at least it does in my testing):

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if (Kmart3[i].get_item_name().length() > 0)
        cout << Kmart3[i].get_item_name().c_str() << "\t" << Kmart3[i].get_item_price() << "\t" << Kmart3[i].get_qty_on_hand() << "\t" << Kmart3[i].get_qty_purchased() << endl;
}
```

Of course, there are a few other issues you'll need to address before the code works as I think you mean for it to work; however, that should stop the crashing.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I actually was doing it by the size of 10, but i changed some stuff and made the size to three. which caused the crash when i used 10 instead of Size of 3.